# Shorten or suppress chapter subtitle in page header

Tags: header-footer

I have some very long chapter subtitles, consisting of places and times, which I don’t want to appear in their entirety on the page head. I would like to have only a specified part of the subtitle appear, specifying that manually for each chapter.

I also would like not to have „Kapitel 1“ automatically added to the header.

Failing that, I would like to only have the chapter title on the page head.

Short working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand\Chapter[2]{
  \chapter[#1: {\itshape#2}]{#1\\\small\itshape#2}
}
\begin{document}
\Chapter{Meister Vreolan}{Unweit der Kaiserstadt Selduris im Jahre 512 nach Großkönig Ábderos.}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Picture showing the problem:
[image]

Comment: You can customize what is written in the header with `fancyheader`. See https://texblog.org/2007/11/07/headerfooter-in-latex-with-fancyhdr/. Just add a new global macro to your document that holds whatever should go into the header of the pages (make sure of that via fancyheader) and update its content every time you call your `\Chapter` macro

Comment: Besides: I'd suggest setting the document's language to german and let LaTeX do the chapter numbering for you. So you don't have to manually write the `Kapitel 1` but provide the title of that chapter only

Comment: @Raven absolutely right. I wrote Kapitel 1 here in the working example. But I don’t want arithmetic titles at all. I shall update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I did what I suggested in my comment and here's the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newcommand{\currentChapterTitle}{}

\newcommand\Chapter[2]{
  \chapter[#1: {\itshape#2}]{#1\\\small\itshape#2}
  \renewcommand{\currentChapterTitle}{#1}
}


% set header contents for even and odd pages
\fancyhead[RE]{\currentChapterTitle}
\fancyhead[CE]{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}

\fancyhead[LO]{\currentChapterTitle}
\fancyhead[CO]{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}

% remove additional page number from footer
\fancyfoot{}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\Chapter{Meister Vreolan}{Unweit der Kaiserstadt Selduris im Jahre 512 nach Großkönig Ábderos.}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

This results in a header like this:
[image: Resulting header]